# Test the result of a char reversed string

Tags: java, junit

Here is a main method that reverses a String. How can programmatically test that the reversed string is correct ?

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String reverseStatement = "reverse this statement";
    String reversed = "";

    for(int count = reverseStatement.length() - 1; count >= 0; --count){
        reversed += String.valueOf(reverseStatement.charAt(count));
    }

    System.out.println("Reversed is - "+reversed);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your reverse code into a separate method, like so:

```
private static String reverse(String string) {
    return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString()
}
```

Be aware that adding a lot of Strings directly (like in your original code) can be *very* slow. I suggest you google for `java.lang.StringBuilder` for further examples.

After that, you can easily test and verify that your method does the correct thing.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String statement = "reverse this statement";
    String reversed = reverse(statement);

    if (!reversed.equals("tnemetats siht esrever")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("the string was not correctly reversed");
    }

    // reversing twice should yield the original string
    if (!statement.equals(reverse(reverse(statement)))) {
        throw new RuntimeException("reversing a string twice should yield the original, but it doesn't");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

again in a loop

```
In While Loop

count=0;
length = originalString.length;

if(!originialString[count].equals(reversedString[length])
{
  System.out.println("BUGGY BUG");
  break; // original and reversed strings are not equal
}

count++;
length--;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided maybe rather slow. Look into something called [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). StringBuffer has a method which will allow you to reverse the String. This is how it works:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(yourstringhere);
sb.reverse();
```

The above code will reverse the String.

Now to check if the reversed String is the String that has been inputed we can simply use the .equals in the String class.

```
    if (sb.toString ().equals (originalString))
{
    System.out.println ("The Strings match");
}
else
{
    System.out.println ("The String don't match");
}
```

Now if you didn't want to do this and just check with what you have. Then you can use the same logic. Use the .equals in the String class to compare your reversedStatement and reversed.

```
        if (string.equals (originalString))
{
    System.out.println ("The Strings match");
}
else
{
    System.out.println ("The String don't match");
}
```